# How can I draw a new single vertex?

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups

I´m trying to make these boots and I need to draw this opening on the front but I don´t have the vertex in the way I needed to. How can I create those new vertex? Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: In Edit mode select edge mode (2 on the keyboard), and hilight the edge where you want the vertex, then right-click and select 'Subdivide' on the popup menu. You can then go into vertex mode, select the new vertex, hit G twice and slide the vertex along the edge to where you want it.

Comment: hello maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> to draw a gap.  Then you can do it with two different ways.

1. Just manually delete the the faces you drew and fill the inside.
2. Or you can use default add-on named loop tool. You can enable it in preference section. Just select the top and bottom face and apply bridge in loop tool.
   Hope that helps.